# Only Update Certain Fields on Put Restify + SQLite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sqlite, restify

I am using [Restify](http://restify.com/) with a SQLite3 database. So far this is what I have for my `put` method:

```
server.put('/users/:userid', function(req, res, next) {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      db.run('UPDATE users SET username = ?, first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?', req.body.username, req.body.first_name, req.body.last_name, req.body.email, hash, req.params.userid, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.json({ message:'Successfully updated user'});
        }
      });
    }
  });
  next();
});
```

In order for this to work one would have to pass in every attribute again:

```
{
    "username": "greg",
    "first_name": "Greg",
    "last_name": "Davis",
    "email": "gdavis@email.com",
    "password": "password"
}
```

Obviously this is redundant if only the email needs to be changed. How could I modify my code so that passing in the following would be enough?

```
{
    "email": "gdavis@email.com",
}
```

I am okay adding in some additional logic to check if a new password is specified, as that more complicated, but adding in logic for every single field seems excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using raw DB queries you might look into using something like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/instance/), which is compatible with sqlite3. You could then retrieve the user object, make only the needed changes and then run update on the object.

Otherwise it looks like creating `if` statements for every possible field is in order.